# ECS Fargate task - send email via SES SMTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-fargate

I'm getting timeout when trying to send via the SMTP endpoint for SES (using port 587) from my fargate tasks. It sends when I run locally so the SES config is correct.

I've tried setting up a VPC Endpoint - but that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how I can enable SMTP from my fargate task?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: By default there is a restriction on E-Mail sending ports from EC2, maybe that's also the case when running Fargate in the VPC? [The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshoot-smtp.html) link to a [form where you can have these limits removed](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request). Have you tried that?